# PostgreSQL select for arrays of composite elements

Tags: arrays, postgresql, composite

I've got a table defined over a composite type:

```
create type footype as (  
a double precision,
b double precision
);  

create table footable as (  
x integer,  
y footype []);
```

How can I use a select statement on the single field of the composite elements contained in the table?

Thanks in advance,
Antonio

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just the usual [array access syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING) followed by the usual [composite type access syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html#AEN7383). So a bit of setup for demonstration purposes:

```
=> insert into footable (x, y) values(1, ARRAY[(1.0,2.0)::footype]);
=> select * from footable;
 x |     y     
---+-----------
 1 | {"(1,2)"}
(1 row)
```

And then:

```
=> select y[1].a, y[1].b from footable where x = 1;
 a | b 
---+---
 1 | 2
(1 row)
```

You can also access the composite type inside a WHERE clause:

```
=> select * from footable where y[1].b < 3;
 x |         y         
---+-------------------
 1 | {"(1,2)"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Can I also define a criterion on a value of a field of the composite type?

Comment: for example if I have to select the records that has value less than 2 on the field b. Can I write this kind of query?

Comment: @Antonio: Yes, things like `select * from footable where y[1].b < 2` work just fine.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, there is one mistake, the word 'as' is wrong in the create table query. You should rather write this:

```
create table footable (
    x integer,  
    y footype []
);
```

Insert data into the table:

```
insert into footable(x, y) values(10, ARRAY[ ROW(1.0,2.0), ROW(3,4)]::footype[] );

# select * from footable;
 x  |         y         
----+-------------------
 10 | {"(1,2)","(3,4)"}
(1 row)
```

Get the data by the fields:

```
# select x, y[1], y[1].a, y[1].b from footable;

 x  |   y   | a | b 
----+-------+---+---
 10 | (1,2) | 1 | 2
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected the solution that didn't work because it had a mistake in the generate_subscripts() function. I have changed the column in this function because it must be an array type column (y), not an atomic one (x):

```
=> select * from (select x, y, generate_subscripts(y,1) as s from footable) as coord where y[s].a = 2.5;
```